# problems in Python Sched

Tags: python

I have created the number of schedulers using python in windows which are running in background.
Can anyone tell me any command to check how many schedulers running on windows and also how can I remove them?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `sched.scheduler`, you can query `sched.scheduler.queue`.

> **scheduler.queue**
>
> Read-only attribute returning a list of upcoming events in the order they will be run. Each event is shown as a named tuple with the following fields: time, priority, action, argument.

In the very [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html) there is also this little piece of advice:

> In multi-threaded environments, the scheduler class has limitations with respect to thread-safety, inability to insert a new task before the one currently pending in a running scheduler, and holding up the main thread until the event queue is empty. Instead, the preferred approach is to use the threading.Timer class instead.

Answer (score 0):

All your schedulers are part of your a single Python process, then you won't be able to count the the individual timers which are scheduled. As the python schedulers are something you write, you can choose to keep a file which would be updated periodically.

If each scheduler is a separate python process, then count the many python processes from your Windows task manager.